# Plot in NDSolveValue

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

```
 e = 1/2; L = 7.5; a = 6,14; M1 = 3/14;
 eq = {y''[x] == 
M1 - y[x] + (3 y[x]^2)/
  L^2 (L - M1 (3 + e^2)) - ((L - 4 M1) (1 - e^2))/L^3 2 y[x]^3, 

 y[0] == a, 

 y'[0] == (Sqrt[
  2 M1 a - a^2 + ((L - M1 (3 + e^2)) 2 a^3)/
   L^2 - ((L - 4 M1) (1 - e^2))/L^3 a^4])};    
U3 = NDSolveValue[eq, y, {x, 0, 50}]
PolarPlot[U3[x], {x, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All]
```

I have solved a second-order differential equation with the initial conditions (aforementioned). My question is that I am not getting the plot if I slightly increase or decrease the initial condition value. Can anyone enlight what might be the problem?

Example: If I take ''a'' in between  6 to 14 I am getting the plot if I vary the value of ''a'' <=6 or >=14  I am not getting the plots, but there is no error in interpolation.[image]

Also, the above mentioned is happening in NDSolveValue, If I use the same in NDSolve I am getting error.

Comment: just one comment. Don't put a=6,14 in the code. It will give you error.What is r^2?

Comment: For some values of `a`,  `U3[x]` is complex.  Maybe you can try `PolarPlot[Re@U3[x], {x, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All]`

Answer (score 2):

You may find `ParametricNDSolveValue` convenient:

```
ClearAll[a]
e = 1/2; L = 7.5; M1 = 3/14;

pndsv = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y''[x] ==  M1 - y[x] + (3 y[x]^2)/
        L^2 (L - M1 (3 + e^2)) - ((L - 4 M1) (1 - e^2))/L^3 2 y[x]^3, 
    y[0] == a, 
    y'[0] == (Sqrt[2 M1 a - a^2 + ((L - M1 (3 + e^2)) 2 a^3)/
         L^2 - ((L - 4 M1) (1 - e^2))/L^3 a^4])}, y, {x, 0, 50}, {a}];
```

For some values of `a` the solution has complex values. For example, for `a = 4`:

```
pndsv[4] /@ Range[0, 5, .5]
```

> {4. + 0. I, 4.06381 + 0.697892 I, 4.2586 + 1.53814 I, 
>    4.59715 + 2.72262 I, 5.12482 + 4.63761 I, 6.09065 + 8.31546 I, 
>    10.0174 + 18.5192 I, 73.9105 - 28.8 I, 8.50536 - 15.3552 I, 
>    5.83542 - 7.36804 I, 5.00329 - 4.18264 I}

To get a non-empty plot you can plot the real part of the solution:

```
Manipulate[PolarPlot[Re @ pndsv[a][x], {x, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All], {a, 0, 30, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: very nice idea. But I have two questions... 1) I exported the output as .avi file. Is there a command or way to slow the speed of the video? 2) How to know in which case I should use ParametricNDSolveValue instead of NDSolveValue? Thanks in advance.